# Radio turning into checkbox in Firefox browser

Tags: html, firefox, checkbox, radio-button, placeholder

I have following simple html code. 3 radio buttons followed by a textbox with placeholder attribute and then followed by a checkbox. When viewed in firefox browser, the 3rd radio keeps turning into checkbox.

1) On mouse over on radio, it reverts back.

2) On removing placeholder attribute on textbox, it goes away.

3) On removing checkbox, it goes away.

Has anyone faced this issue ? is it a firefox bug ?

```
    <input name="source" value="1" checked="checked" type="radio">Radio Button 1<br>
    <input name="source" value="2" type="radio">Radio Button 2<br>
    <input name="source" value="3" type="radio">Radio Button 3

    <br><br>
    <input name="mybox" size="50" maxlength="50" type="text" placeholder="placeholder">

    <br><br>
    <input name="mycheck" value="true" type="checkbox">Checkbox
```

[JSFiddle Link - View In Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/kwpuxth1/)

[Screen Shot Link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=f730641)

Comment: works fine for me using the latest FF, what version do you have?

Comment: Firefox - 38.0.5 - works fine

Comment: I have the same version 38.0.5

Comment: Here is the screen shot [Link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=f730641)

Comment: works fine here Firefox too

Comment: I agree with humble.rumble. Perhaps it's a plugin interfering?